# Organise large dataset into separate lines

Tags: python, token

I have a large raw data set which I want to organise into separate lines. The data is delimited. I want to organise so there are 8 delimiters in one line followed by a location, then the new line.

Raw Data:

468|2016-06-17||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||London 468|2016-06-16||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.european||Yorkshire and the Humber 468|2016-06-18||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||London

Desired Output:

468|2016-06-17||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||London

468|2016-06-16||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.european||Yorkshire and the Humber

468|2016-06-18||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||London

following help from akash karothiya I now have this

```
data = open("raw_data.txt", "r")
new = []
for i in data.read().split(' '):
    if '|' in i:
        new.append(i)
    else:
        new.append(str(new[-1]) + ' ' + i )
        new.remove(new[-2])
print(new)
```

but this results in the \n being printed instead of a new line, why? In this example, Yorkshire and the Humber should be at the end of one line:

['468|2016-06-17||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.international.england.story.36558237.page||london\n468|2016-07-03||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.european_championship.2016.media_asset.36695497.page||London\n06b|2016-06-21||Computer|responsive|news|news.page|news|yorkshire and the', 'humber\n468|2016-06-18||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.international.england.story.36558237.page||london']

Comment: Can you add a portion of the input data please?

Comment: It seems a very simple problem. What have you tried so far and why is not working? do you have the data in a file?

Comment: @Tiger-222 The Input data is as present in the file, the desired data is what I want to achieve, thanks.

Comment: I can see the data is separated with space( `\s` ) , therefore you can simply use `input.split(' ')`

Comment: Based on example data it seems, that the rows are delimited by a whitespace, but also, there are whitespaces within the fields ("west midlands"). If this is the case, your task is impossible, as it's impossible to say where one row ends and the next begins. Unless you can say for example, that the first cell is always a number and there are no numbers in the last cell.

Comment: @skoll Yes, this is why I thought tokenising would be best because there are 8 " | " in each line. Then I would say take remaining string, but how to differentiate between the location at the end and the following line. The following line does not always start with numbers also..

Comment: what about whitespace as a delimiter ? can't we use that

Comment: @akashkarothiya west midlands is a single location so using white space would not work here unfortunately..

Comment: @Sonic18 You need to figure out an explicit rule for differentiating the last column from the first. If checking for numbers doesn't work, maybe there's no whitespace in the first column?

Comment: @Sonic18 here you go,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this :

```
data = '''468|2016-06-17||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||london 468|2016-06-16||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.european||west midlands 468|2016-06-17||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||india'''

new = []
for i in data.split(' '):
    if '|' in i:
        new.append(i)
    else:
        new.append(str(new[-1]) + ' ' + i )
        new.remove(new[-2])
print(new)

['468|2016-06-17||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||london',
 '468|2016-06-16||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.european||west midlands',
 '468|2016-06-17||Mobile|responsive|sport|sport.football.england||india']
```

Comment: My output seems to be printing "\n" instead of an actual new line, why is this?